# rand() doesn't create random numbers

Tags: c++, random

I have a simple program that so far creates 5 community cards (all ints). I've managed to set these (and they are global variables, that's on purpose), but every time I run the program, they create the same number. Below is the code.

```
int communityCards[5];
int playerCards[2];
int opponentCards[2];
int communityValues[5];
int playerValues[2];
int opponentValues[2];

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (i < 5) {
            communityCards[i] = rand() % 52 - i;
            for (int a = 0; communityCards[a]!=0; a++) {
                communityCards[i]==communityCards[a]?communityCards[i]++: a = a;
            }
        }
        printf("%i ", communityCards[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: just check the manual. you have to call `srand` first.

Comment: You should start using the newer random generator. 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/uniform_real_distribution/uniform_real_distribution/

Comment: @user814628 - that won't change the behavior of not seeding the generator. The program will still produce the same set of values on every run.

Answer (score 3):

You want to call `srand(time(NULL));` once at the beginning of `main`.

As an aside, however, it looks like the rest of your logic is *probably* wrong. In particular, it looks like right now you could (for example) deal five aces as the community cards (or is your loop/conditional intended to fix that?)

Usually you'd want to fill a deck, shuffle it with `std::random_shuffle`, then move cards from there to the community, player's and opponent's hands.

Comment: `time` have 1 second precision, so multiple copies launched at once will produce same result.

Comment: @SigTerm: The C++ standard doesn't specify the precision of `time`. 1 second is common, but it could be a nanosecond or an hour.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, Wow, I've never heard that one before. I haven't run across anyone claiming anything but one second until now. Good to know, thanks.

Comment: It is specifically meant to fix that, I check with the communityValues[i]==communityValues[a].

Comment: @chris: I should probably also add that although the C standard doesn't specify its precision (or epoch), if memory serves POSIX does specify both (i.e., that `time` returns seconds since midnight, 1 Jan 1970).

Comment: @JerryCoffin, Yeah, I think so, and many implementations follow that.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`srand`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand) just once with a proper seed before calling `rand`. Usually, `srand(time(0))` is used.

Alternatively, C++11 provides a lot of much better [random number generators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) with fine-grained specifications (`rand` provides basically no guarantee regarding the quality of the numbers it produces).

Answer (score 2):

write `srand` func at the beginning of your program 
It will take current time as seed

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    // STUFF
}
```